# Querying object's field array values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

If I have a class like this:

```
public class Car {
 public string Model { get; set; }
 public List<string> Types { get; set; }
}
```

and do:

```
Car _car = new Car();
_car.Model = "1992";
List<string> _types = new List<string>() { "New", "Old" };
_car.Types = _types
```

and save these kinds of objects in MongoDB, how do I get all cars that have `type == "New"` in C# MongoDB? I need to query `Car.Type == "New"` I'm going to visit the class and look in its `"Types"` array and find the matching object in the array and return the whole class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB query language can access arrays transparently. So you can just do:

```
db.cars.find({Types:"New"})
```

and it will return all documents which have an entry in the Types array which is equal to the string "New". Check [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray) for more information.